Docker container DNS resolution not working
I have a Docker container running on an ARM64 Rocky Linux 8.7 EC2 instance that cannot connect to the Internet, even if I start a container with --net=host. The host itself is able to access the Internet. The Docker network config and IPtables look correct. Restarting Docker gives the same result.
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "MacAddress": "xx",
                    "NetworkID": "xx",
                    "EndpointID": "xx",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "DNSNames": null
                }

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere 

The contents of /etc/resolve.conf are the same as the host instance, which I already know is able to route properly.
nslookup on the container cannot reach the nameservers.
The container is able to resolve its own gateway, 127.17.0.2.
What is the issue?
Additional commands:
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

Upon inspecting the Docker bridge network, I see a gateway value. I don't see this value on a VM where my container is able to connect to the Internet.
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },

$ ip route
default via 10.x.x.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.x.x.9 metric 100 
10.x.x.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.x.x.9 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 

I tried again with --net=host, and this time I was able to curl an external IP through the container.
$ docker exec -it compassionate_bouman curl 172.217.14.238

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

Will investigate further.

Please share the output of command cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward, run at your host OS.

@paladin The output is 1.

Have you actually tried pinging an IP first (with --net=host)? From within and outside of the container (just to make sure that the ping in particular really works on the "host side"). I'm not seeing how things could differ L3-or-below-wise when you are using the same network namespace...

@TomYan I swear the first time I tried it didn't work, but I ran another container with --net=host and tried curling a google IP and it did work. Will update the Q, this will hopefully make investigating easier

I don't quite see how with --net=host if /etc/resolv.conf is the same, nslookup would fail on one side but succeed on the other. What exactly are the outputs from each side? Can you add that to your post?

@TomYan added to the question

Actually I meant like the respective output of nslookup.

@TomYan Ah sorry, I hadn't had my coffee yet. nslookup does work as expected with --net=host.

I want to answer by using comment, but my reputation is not enough
I think the problem has been resolved to some extent, but I am leaving this answer for reference.
I had a similar experience before and I solved by changing ip route rule
Please check your ip route configuration to ensure it is set properly. (When similar case re occured) Below is an example of what it might look like:
ip route
default via 172.21.0.1 dev eth0
127.0.0.0/8 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
127.0.0.1 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
127.255.255.255 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
172.17.0.0/16 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo # this make all 172 traffics go to loopback
172.17.0.3 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
172.17.255.255 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo

You can fix it by deleting the incorrect route and adding the correct one:
ip route del 172.17.0.0/16 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
ip route add 172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0


Thanks, but I'm not sure this is the issue. I've got 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1  which I think is ok. At least, that rule is working well on another machine.

Make sure that the Docker daemon is configured to use the correct DNS servers, typically located at /etc/docker/daemon.json. Add the following configuration if it's not already present: {
"dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
Restart the docker. Also check Container DNS Configuration /etc/resolv.conf inside the docker. If they are not, you can start the container like this: docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -it <your_image> ; Also, check the firewall sudo iptables -L -v -n

@MaxHaase I am restricted to using my corporate network's name servers. the IP tables look correct.
